# How do I call an xll addin function from vba?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have a 3rd party XLL addin I'd like to wrap in my own custom vba function. How would I call the 3rd party function from my code?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Edit:** There are at least two ways to do this:

---

**Option 1:** `Application.Run(...)`

This looks like the best way to go about it, since your arguments are automatically converted to an appropriate type before being sent to the XLL function.

```
Public Function myVBAFunction(A as Integer, B as String, C as Double)
    myVBAFunction = Application.Run("XLLFunction", A, B, C)
End Sub
```

See [this page](http://www.planatechsolutions.com/xllplus-online/faq.htm#VisualBasic) for more details.

---

**Option 2:** `Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(...)`

With this method, you will have to convert any arguments into string format before passing them to the XLL function.

```
Public Function myVBAFunction(A as Integer, B as String, C as Double)
    dim macroCall as String
    macroCall = "XLLFunction(" & A
    macroCall = macroCall & "," & Chr(34) & B & Chr(34)
    macroCall = macroCall & "," & C
    macroCall = macroCall & ")"
    myVBAFunction = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(macroCall)
End Sub
```

See [this page](http://www.planatechsolutions.com/xllplus-online/start_mt_demo_background_xla.htm) for more details.

Comment: My pleasure. I'm glad it was useful

Comment: Now, if someone can figure out why the entire answer shows up as <code> formatted, I'd love to know!

Comment: Looks great to me. Did you try a hard browser refresh?

Comment: Yes, I did. Maybe it is just an IE thing. When I look at it, everything from the end of the first Sub to the end of the second Sub has the same font. Only the stuff before & after either sub is in the normal format. Oh well!

Comment: I have a question: Does Option 1 also work if arguments A, B, C are complex objects like Range, Worksheet, etc.?

Comment: @Steve06: Yes, I believe they do. `Application.run("Function", ...)` takes all of the arguments after "Function" as `Variant' types, so you can pass in anything you like.

Comment: _Option 1_ also works to call methods in (even unloaded) **XLA add-ins** [if you use the correct method string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49402129/2822719). Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I know this is a way late answer, but I discovered this alternate method and think it's worth sharing.  You can declare the 3rd party functions in the same manner as a Win32 call.  This has the added benefit of showing up in the Intellisense completion when you are coding.

```
Private Declare Function XLLFunction Lib "C:\PathTo3rdPartyDLL\3rdParty.xll" (ByVal A as Integer, ByVal B as String, C as Double) As Double

Sub Function myVBAFunction(A as Integer, B as String, C as Double) as Double
    myVBAFunction = XLLFunction(A, B, C)
End Sub
```