# Application.Run for Macro returning Arrays

Tags: excel, vba, xll

i want to call a function "arrayfun1" in vba from an xll-addin with "Application.Run"

```
Sub test()
Dim val As Variant
val = Application.Run("arrayfun1", arg1, arg2, ...)
End Sub
```

this works for functions that return just one output, but not for functions that return arrays. However, if i use the function as Arrayformula in a sheet it works. But i am looking for a programatical solution.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found this example at Chip's website:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/passingandreturningarrays.htm

```
Sub AAATest()
    Dim Arr() As Long
    Dim N As Long
    Arr = LoadNumbers(Low:=101, High:=110)
    If IsArrayAllocated(Arr:=Arr) = True Then
        For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
           Debug.Print Arr(N)
        Next N
    Else
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Code in case Arr is not allocated.
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    End If
End Sub

Function LoadNumbers(Low As Long, High As Long) As Long()
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Returns an array of Longs, containing
    ' the numbers from Low to High. The 
    ' number of elements in the returned
    ' array will vary depending on the 
    ' values of Low and High.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Declare ResultArray as a dynamic array
    ' to be resized based on the values of
    ' Low and High.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim ResultArray() As Long
    Dim Ndx As Long
    Dim Val As Long
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Ensure Low <= High
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Low > High Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Resize the array
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ReDim ResultArray(1 To (High - Low + 1))
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Fill the array with values.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Val = Low
    For Ndx = LBound(ResultArray) To UBound(ResultArray)
        ResultArray(Ndx) = Val
        Val = Val + 1
    Next Ndx
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Return the array.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    LoadNumbers = ResultArray()

End Function
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt solve the problem. the problem is that the function itself returns an error. `val = Application.Run("arrayfun1", arg1, arg2, ...)` gives me back "#uncalculated".

Comment: The code I post is just an example, you need to modify the code and you will be able to receive an array as result.

Comment: i understand what you are suggesting but the function is in a xll-file so i can only run it with `Application.Run(...)`  i can not see the function itself.

Comment: Then the function should be modified to return an array.

Comment: The function does return an array when it's called in the worksheet; he's asking how to get the array into VBA without using the worksheet as intermediary.

Answer (score 0):

You can call into the function using a `Declare Function` statement in VBA (though you'll need to acquire some tools to convert the parameters from VBA format to Excel SDK format, and vice versa for the return value), or using `ExecuteExcel4Macro` or `Evaluate` (though those require converting all the arguments to strings first).

See this web page:
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2014/12/13/calling-xlamxllautomation-udfs-from-vba-evaluate-run-or-reference/

And this question:
[How do I call an xll addin function from vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375552/how-do-i-call-an-xll-addin-function-from-vba)