# Run-time error 1004 - couldn't find BloombergUI

Tags: vba, excel, bloomberg

I'm running a batch file that executes a VBScript that runs a macro in an Excel sheet on Bloomberg Terminal.

The excel sheet contains a lot of BDP formulas in cells. These all work fine. Initially, I a had a problem updating the data from Bloomberg and running the macro but this was solved by using bloombergui.xla.RefreshAllStaticData + a timer.

The macro runs perfectly when executed manually in excel but I am getting a "run-time error 1004 couldn't find bloombergui.xla..." when trying to automate it via batch & VBS.

Any ideas how to solve this? I think I have exhausted all options via google.

Macro:

```
Sub UpdateWeekly()

Application.Run "bloombergUI.xla!RefreshAllStaticData"
Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:25")), "WeeklyPDF"

End Sub

Sub WeeklyPDF()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:V225").Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="O:\LOCATION" & Format(Date, "MMMM-DD-YYYY") & " " & "Weekly", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

Application.PrintCommunication = False

End Sub
```

VBScript:

```
Dim args, objExcel

Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open args(0)
objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.Run "UpdateCreditWeekly"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)
objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Is the xla file in the same workbook that you are using?

Comment: which line is giving you the error?

Comment: The xla file is just stored on the local disk.

Comment: Error comming from Application.Run "bloombergUI.xla!RefreshAllStaticData"

Comment: I think before calling `Application.Run "bloombergUI.xla!RefreshAllStaticData"` you need to check whether add-in is loaded or not

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation or searching for an answer before posting the question?  There are plenty of examples on [so] and elsewhere... Kinda feels like I wasted my time putting the answer together for you..

Comment: Thanks for your help ashlee, I've tried a lot of options on here and none have worked. Any suggestion which I should try?

Comment: @Andrew Sometimes bloomberg Add-in fails to load when Excel is instantiated programmatically ... I think you need to load it again every time. please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213375/loading-addins-when-excel-is-instantiated-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bloomberg Add-in fails to load when Excel is instantiated programmatically ... I think you need to load it again every time.

**Ensure the AddIn is there before calling** `Application.Run "bloombergUI.xla!RefreshAllStaticData"`

```
    Sub UpdateWeekly()
        Dim blpAddin As Workbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Set blpAddin = Workbooks("bloombergUI.xla")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not blpAddin Is Nothing Then ' Check if add-in is loaded or not 
            Application.Run "bloombergUI.xla!RefreshAllStaticData" ' refresh Bloomberg formulas
            Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:25")), "WeeklyPDF" ' wait till bloomberg Formulas calculation complete
        Else
            Debug.Print "Bloomberg Add-in is not loaded"
        End If
    End Sub
```

**If Add-in is not there then you need to Add/load add-in**

```
    'To load the Add-in
    Application.Addins.Add(file path & name)
```

**OR**

```
    AddIns("Add-In Name").Installed = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your syntax is incorrect.

> Application.Run can be used to run a macro written in Visual Basic or
>   the Microsoft Excel macro language, or to run a function in a DLL or
>   XLL.
>
> The macro you specify **can be either a string with the macro name**,
>   or **a Range object indicating where the function is**, *or* **a
>   register ID for a registered DLL (XLL) function**. If a string is
>   used, the string will be evaluated in the context of the active sheet.

Also, if you're using a newer version of Excel you're going to have further problems because I believe `XLA` is an older filetype, since replaced by `XLAM`.

See the links below for more information, **especially [this](http://run%20excel%20macro%20from%20outside%20excel%20using%20vbscript%20from%20command%20line/) one and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/375753/8112776) one**.

---

### More Info:

- MSDN: [Application.Run method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-run-method-excel)
- Ron de Bruin : [How do I use Application.Run in Excel](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm)
- Stack Overflow : [Run Excel Macro from Outside Excel Using VBScript From Command Line](http://run%20excel%20macro%20from%20outside%20excel%20using%20vbscript%20from%20command%20line/)
- Stack Overflow : [How do I call an xll addin function from vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/375753/8112776)