# Calling an XLA add-in method (function/sub) when the add-in is not loaded

Tags: vba, excel, xla

I need to call a method that is provided by a third-party XL**A** add-in via my VBA code.

There are already [answers for doing this with a *loaded* XL**L** add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/375753/2822719), but the intention is to call the method directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [e.James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/375753/2822719) for calling an XLL add-in, I figured out the right format to use if the Add-in **isn't already loaded**. You can use `Application.Run` for calling methods inside an **.xla** Add-in the following way:

If we assume that the path to our .xla file is `C:\Program Files\example.xla` and the method we want to call is `ExampleMethod` expecting one integer parameter, then the call would be as follows:

```vb
' Method call without return value
Private Sub XLAExample()
    Application.Run "'C:\Program Files\example.xla'!ExampleMethod", 10
End Sub

' Method call with return value (check if you can declare correct type for return value!)
Private Function XLAExample() As Variant
    XLAExample = Application.Run("'C:\Program Files\example.xla'!ExampleMethod", 10)
End Sub
```

So you will need to construct a string of the form

```vb
"'<ADDIN_PATH>'!<METHOD_NAME>"
```

for the call and then just append all needed parameters like

```vb
Application.Run <PATH_AND_METHOD>, <PARAMETER_1>, <PARAMETER_2>, ...
```

Unfortunately, I found that [CuberChase's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17468786/2822719) that declares the method directly like an API call doesn't work with my specific .xla file, maybe it would have needed to be loaded to work.